# db2 tables altered, reorg

Tags: db2

When I alter a table in DB, I need to reorg it:

```
Call Sysproc.admin_cmd ('reorg Table myTable');
```

if I had done many modifications, how can I know which tables need a reorg?

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about programming problems.  Database management questions belong on DBA.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also when asking DB management issues for DB2, please specify *which* DB2 you are asking about.  There are three members of the DB2 family.  One for z/OS on mainframes, one for IBM i on Power Systems, and one for Linux, Unix, Windows [LUW].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reorg is necessary when the table content has changed (lots of inserts, lots of updates, many deletes, a combination of all of that) and you can query which tables need reorganization via 'REORGCHK'

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001971.html